# PHP: headers already sent when using fwrite but not when using fputcsv

Tags: php, file-io, http-headers

I know the theory behind this error however it is now driving me crazy again. I'm using [Tonic](http://peej.github.io/tonic/) in my application. With this library you redirect all traffic to your `dispatch.php` script which then executes the appropriate `Resource` and that `Resource` return a `Response` which is displayed (output) by `dispatch.php`.

The output method of `Response` look like this:

```
/**
 * Output the response
 */
public function output()
{
    foreach ($this->headers as $name => $value) {
        header($name.': '.$value, true, $this->responseCode());
    }
    echo $this->body;
}
```

So AFAIK this tells us that you can't write anything to php output in your `Resource`.

I now have a `Resource` that dynamically generates a csv from an input csv and outputs it to the browser (it converts 1 column of the data to a different format).

```
$csv = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// sets header
$response->__set('contentDisposition:', 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
while (($line = fgetcsv($filePointer, 0, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
    // generate line
    fputcsv($csv, $line);
}
fclose($filePointer);
return $response;
```

This works 100% fine. No issue with headers and the correct file is generated and offered for download. This is already confusing because we are writing to the output before headers are set? What does fputcsv actually do?

I have a second resource that does a similar thing but it outputs a custom file format (text file).

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// sets header
$response->__set('contentDisposition:', 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
while (($line = fgetcsv($filePointer, 0, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
    // generate a record (multiple lines) not shown / snipped
    fwrite($output, $record);
}
fclose($filePointer);
return $response;
```

The only difference is that it uses fwrite instead of fputcsv and bang

```
 headers already sent by... // line number = fwrite()
```

This is very confusing! IMHO it should actually fail in both cases? Why does the first one work? how can I get the second one to work?
(I can generate a huge string containing the file and put that into the responses body and it works. However files could be rather big (up to 50 mb) and hence want to avoid this.)

Comment: Shouldn't you `fwrite` to `$response` not to `$output`?

Comment: **The known** answer to this kind of error http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987

Comment: I know this as i stated in my question to actually prevent this kind of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution. I'm not going to mark it as answer for a while because maybe someone comes up with something better (simpler) than this.

First a comment about fwrite and fputcsv:

fputcsv has a complete different source and not much in common with fwrite (it does not call fwrite internally, it's a separate function in C source code). Since I don't know C I can't tell why they behave differently but they do.

Solution:

The generated files can be "large" depending on input and hence generating the whole file by string concatenation and keeping it in memory isn't a great solution.

I googled a bit and found mod_xsendfile for apache. This works by setting a custom header in php containing the path to the file to be sent to the user. The mod then removes that custom header and sends the file as response.

The problem with mod_xsendfile is that it is not compatible with mod_rewrite, which I use too. You will get 404 errors. To solve this you need to add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

to the according place in apache config (don't rewrite if the request is for an actual physically existing file). However that's not enough. You need to set the header X-Sendfile in a php script that was not rewritten, is an actual existing php file.

So in the \Tonic\Resource class generating the file at the end I redirect to an above outlined script:

```
$response->__set('location', $url . "?fileName=" . urlencode($fileName));
$response->code = \Tonic\Response::FOUND;
return $response;
```

In the download script we redirect to in above snippet just do (validation stuff omitted):

```
$filePath = trim($_GET['fileName']);
header ('X-Sendfile: ' . $filePath);    
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filePath . '"');
```

and the browser will display a download dialog for the generated file.

You will also need to create cron job to delete the generated files.

```
/usr/bin/find /path/to/generatedFiles/ -type f -mmin +60 -exec rm {} +
```

this will delete all files older than 60 min in directory `/path/to/generatedFiles`.

I use ubuntu server so you can add it to the file

```
/etc/cron.daily/standard
```

or generated a new file in that directory or generated a new file in `/etc/cron.hourly` containing that command.

Note:

I name the generated files after the sha1 hash of the input csv file so the name is unique and if someone repeats the same requests several times in a short period you can just return the already generated file a second time.

Answer (score 0):

`$record` is not set, generating an error of level `NOTICE`. If you have `error_reporting` to `true`, PHP will put this error in the output before sending the headers.

Set `error_reporting` to false and keep an eye on your logs instead.

Comment: Still. What happens if you disable error_reporting and look in your logs?

Comment: If I generate a string instead of writing to a file and output that it works. My "file creation logic" is correct and all variables are set. The issue is on how to properly return the generated content especially considering ti can be several MB in size.

Comment: Still. Your code puts out content before the headers. Find out what content that is, and you have the answer.

Comment: I'm aware of that if you would have read my question. Simply said writing to php://output using fwrite() -> error. Using fputcsv -> works. Why? (AFAIK fputcsv() uses fwrite() internally)

Comment: I understand that. But there will be a message telling you why. Try to get that message. Another thing you could do is use Wireshark to sniff the actual contents your script is outputting.